# Remove Right Click Print Context Menu from Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

**Is there any way that I can remove the Print item from the context menu when you right-click on an email with VBA?**

I am forever right-clicking to reply to an email, only to accidentally click `Print` and have Outlook send it directly to the printer quicker than I can stop it.

[image]

**NB:** I am using Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the link TcKs provide, that was pretty simple.
In the example below I check the type of the item so that it only affects e-mails and not calendar items.
To enter the code in outlook, Type Alt + F11, then expand the Microsoft Office Outlook Objects in the Project pane.  Then double click the ThisOutlookSession.  Then paste this code into the code window.  I don't like to check captions like this as you can run into issues with internationalization.  But I didn't see an ActionID or anything on the Command.  There was a FaceID but that is just the id of the printer icon.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay(ByVal CommandBar As Office.CommandBar, ByVal Selection As Selection)

   Dim cmdTemp As Office.CommandBarControl

   If Selection.Count > 0 Then

      Select Case TypeName(Selection.Item(1))

         Case "MailItem"

            For Each cmdTemp In CommandBar.Controls

               If cmdTemp.Caption = "&Print" Then

                  cmdTemp.Delete
                  Exit For

               End If

            Next cmdTemp

         Case Else

            'Debug.Print TypeName(Selection.Item(1))

      End Select

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Outlook 2013 anymore, although I replaced `&Print` with `&Quick Print` (which is the name of the context menu entry in Outlook 2013).

Comment: @fero Do you mean that it worked after you changed to `&Quick Print`?  If not, did you ever find a solution for Outlook 2013?  Thanks!

Comment: No, I meant that it did _not_ work although I changed it to `&Quick Print`. And no, I didn't find a solution for it. (Now using Outlook 2016)

Answer (score 8):

Thera is sample how to programaticly working with Outlook:
[How to: Customize an Item Context Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176426.aspx)